# Setting boolean values in pandas dataframe (by date) based on column header membership in other dataframe (by date)

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, intersection

I have two pandas dataframes (X and Y) and am trying to populate a third (Z) with boolean values based on interrelationships between the axes of X and the columns/constituents of Y.  I could only manage to do this via nested loops and the code works on my toy example but is too slow for my actual data set.

```
# define X, Y and Z
idx=pd.date_range('2016-1-31',periods=3,freq='M')
codes = list('ABCD')
X = np.random.randn(3,4)
X = pd.DataFrame(X,columns=codes,index=idx)

Y = [['A','A','B'],['C','B','C'],['','C','D']]
Y = pd.DataFrame(Y,columns=idx)

Z = pd.DataFrame(columns=X.columns, index=X.index)
```

As you can see the index of X matches the columns of Y in this example.  In my real example the columns of Y are a subset of the index of X.

Z's axes match X's.  I want to populate elements of Z with True if the column header of Z is in the column of Y with header equal to the index of Z.  My working code is as follows:

```
for r in Y:
    for c in Z:
        Z.loc[r,c] = c in Y[r].values
```

The code is pretty clean and short but it takes a LONG time to run on the larger data sets.  I'm hoping there is vectorised way to achieve the same much faster.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) method, where values of DataFrame are converted to columns and columns to values of DataFrames. Last test `NaN` by [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html):

```
print (Y.replace({'':np.nan})
        .stack()
        .reset_index(0)
        .set_index(0, append=True)
        .squeeze()
        .unstack()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .notnull())

                A      B     C      D
2016-01-31   True  False  True  False
2016-02-29   True   True  True  False
2016-03-31  False   True  True   True
```

Another solution with `pivot`:

```
print (Y.replace({'':np.nan})
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='a')
        .pivot(index='level_1', columns='a', values='level_0')
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .rename_axis(None)        
        .notnull())

                A      B     C      D
2016-01-31   True  False  True  False
2016-02-29   True   True  True  False
2016-03-31  False   True  True   True
```

EDIT by comment:

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) if indexes are unique and then [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) by `False`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# define X, Y and Z
idx=pd.date_range('2016-1-31',periods=5,freq='M')
codes = list('ABCD')
X = np.random.randn(5,4)
X = pd.DataFrame(X,columns=codes,index=idx)

Y = [['A','A','B'],['C','B','C'],['','C','D']]
Y = pd.DataFrame(Y,columns=idx[:3])
Z = pd.DataFrame(columns=X.columns, index=X.index)

print (X)
                   A         B         C         D
2016-01-31  0.810348 -0.737780 -0.523869 -0.585772
2016-02-29 -1.126655 -0.494999 -1.388351  0.460340
2016-03-31 -1.578155  0.950643 -1.699921  1.149540
2016-04-30 -2.320711  1.263740 -1.401714  0.090788
2016-05-31  1.218036  0.565395  0.172278  0.288698

print (Y)
  2016-01-31 2016-02-29 2016-03-31
0          A          A          B
1          C          B          C
2                     C          D

print (Z)
              A    B    C    D
2016-01-31  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-02-29  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-03-31  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-04-30  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-05-31  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

```
Y1 = Y.replace({'':np.nan})
      .stack()
      .reset_index(name='a')
      .pivot(index='level_1', columns='a', values='level_0')
      .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
      .rename_axis(None)
      .notnull()
print (Y1)
                A      B     C      D
2016-01-31   True  False  True  False
2016-02-29   True   True  True  False
2016-03-31  False   True  True   True

print (Y1.reindex(X.index).fillna(False))
                A      B      C      D
2016-01-31   True  False   True  False
2016-02-29   True   True   True  False
2016-03-31  False   True   True   True
2016-04-30  False  False  False  False
2016-05-31  False  False  False  False
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great.  There is one remaining issue in that I want to force Z to have the same axes as X (Y's axes are a subset).  I notice that if I make X and Z dataframes within a panel this happens automatically with the remaining elements populated by NaN.  How would I stretch the result above to the same axes as X if I was not using a panel? for example if X had an additional two rows in the index